# How would you translate "Quality time"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

Por ejemplo si tu quieres tomar tiempo con tu enamorad@ o con tu familia. En inglés, nosotros lo llamamos "Quality time".

Ustedes pueden describir cual es la mejor traducción (o algo diferente)? (En ingles u español)

> Tiempo de cualidad

OR

> Tiempo de calidad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La expresión que más oigo para ese significado es "buenos momentos" (o "buenos ratos"). En bastante menor medida encuentro a veces la expresión "momentos de calidad".

Muy rara vez escucho decir en español "tiempo de calidad", y la mayoría de las veces es un texto escrito que ha sido traducido del inglés, o en el contexto de una charla sobre el argumento de una película o un libro originalmente en inglés. También es cada vez más frecuente en los ambientes influenciados por la cultura estadounidense, como algunas zonas de latinoamérica.

Cuando se ve esta expresión (tiempo de calidad), generalmente suele ser para reforzar la idea de comparación "calidad" contra "cantidad".

En los contextos en que se habla de recuerdos, la mayoría de las veces se emplea el término "momentos", y algo menos el término "ratos", reemplazando casi por completo al término "tiempo":

*Sólo quedan los **buenos momentos**, aquellos que por más tiempo que pase, jamás se olvidan.*

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. Yo sí he escuchado "tiempo de calidad", pero creo que es una traducción literal de la expresión inglesa.

Comment: Does this also work for the sexual context? Lo funciona para el contexto sexual tambien? http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Quality+Time

Comment: Yes, these nice moments are specially "buenos momentos" in that context :)

Answer (score 6):

La expresión correcta es "Tiempo de **calidad**". `Cualidad` define una propiedad

> Los metales tienen la **cualidad** de conducir la electricidad

mientras que `calidad` se refiere a la excelencia de dichas propiedades

> Ese material es de buena **calidad**

Dado que `quality time` expresa la excelencia del tiempo pasado junto a alguien o haciendo algo, el término correcto es `calidad` y no `cualidad`.

Answer (score 2):

`Cualidad` in Spanish means an attribute. `Calidad` means quality. Since in English the word quality has both meanings, you have to put in in context. When you use the word quality to mean attribute, use "cualidad." Otherwise, use "calidad."

Comment: @Diego veo que estás editando muchas publicaciones para mejorar su formato. ¡Excelente! En este caso utilizas un formato muy particular. Dado que el sitio se ve bastante afectado por las ediciones (como hay pocas preguntas, la rotación de la pantalla de inicio es bastante pequeña), sugiero que consensuemos lo máximo el estilo, para que no venga alguien en el futuro y opte por modificar el formato utilizando otra opción. En [How should we format text?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2440/1674) guifa sugirió unas líneas generales que podrían ser útiles para esto. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui. Estás en lo cierto. He visto algún post que no he tocado porque si yo viese mis propios edits en la sección "review" los cancelaría como "no improvement". Otros tienen alguna cosa mínima, para resaltar una palabra clave (como en este caso) y yo soy más de usar citas con "> ..." que con el estilo gris de _coding_ (totalmente subjetivo, como bien apuntas). Me animé a hacer edits tras la parranda con las etiquetas. Vi un par de etiquetas un poco raras. Si quieres hacer limpieza de otras etiquetas o similar avísame, que si tengo tiempo ya me pongo.

Comment: @Diego no si realmente tus ediciones son extremadamente útiles, contribuyen a ir estandarizando el formato y mejorar la legibilidad. Por ello, mil gracias, de veras. En cuanto al uso de `calidad`, a mí me gusta más el formato _calidad_, pero eso va a gustos. En la publicación que enlacé en mi anterior comentario publicó guifa una respuesta interesante que podría convertirse en canónica si nos parece a todos bien.

Comment: @Diego (sigo). En cuanto a etiquetas, ¡hay trabajo! Por ejemplo [¿Deberíamos juntar modismos / frases idiomáticas / expresiones en una única etiqueta? Should we use a unique tag for idioms?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2531/1674)

Answer (score 1):

La traducción correcta es "*Tiempo de Calidad*".

La expresión "*tiempo de cualidad*" no existe en español.

Tampoco existe una expresión concreta, pero se podría traducir como "*Un rato agradable*".

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Puede describir por que es correcta?